# Hyperledger Composer Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "hlfv1"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I was following the developer guide they have on the composer website and I encountered this error while trying to deploy the business network definition to the fabric.I'm using:

- composer-client v0.7.6
- node - v6.10.3
- npm - v5.0.2
- xcode - 4.8.4

[These are the logs](https://gist.github.com/Binay1/3f78b9f4fda1b07bf318c7bf517c2531).

[These are the npm logs](https://gist.github.com/Binay1/02f4188fd6cecee2d7a571dd6c2108cb)

Comment: Can you please paste the results of running:
`npm uninstall -g composer-cli` followed by
`npm install -g composer-cli`

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.1 -- 4.x would appear to be very old.

Comment: composer-client version is incorrect -- we have not released 0.7.6 yet!

Comment: Please downgrade to npm 4.x -- we have seen issues with npm 5.x. I am using npm 3.10.10.

Comment: For reference, I use Node version 6.9.5. `nvm` is a good tool to easily switch versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by uninstalling and reinstalling docker